# Shareable component in ES5

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-5

modern javascript framework like Vue, React and angular has support to create shareable component across page/module in web app.
How the best way I achieve this using HTML + ES5? Any library or framework?
I am using legacy code that doesn't support ES6

Comment: Maybe you are looking for [Web Components](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create the HTML elements from JS and either bring a `.css` file with it for styling purposes or style it with JS. And then you would just import it to your HTML like so:

```html
<script src="yourcomponent/index.js"></script>
```

You can also use a `cdn` to deploy your component.

Example `index.js` in your component:

```js
function createRoot() {
  const rootElement = document.createElement("div");

  document.body.appendChild(rootElement);

  return rootElement;
}

function createComponent(root = createRoot(), elementType, className) {
   const componentWrapper = document.createElement(elementType);
   componentWrapper.setAttribute("class", className);

   return componentWrapper;
}


// usage

// you can pass root or not
const component = createComponent(document.getElementById("root"), "div", "my-component-wrapper");
```

You can then append extra DOM nodes to it or apply functionality. All of which wil be able to be carried over with your script.

Hope this serves as inspiration :)